# How do I find the bounding box of this contour?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm relatively new to scripting. (I know quite a bit but I also don't know quite a bit.)


I'm trying to have a simple script use OpenCV-Python to subtract two frames from a webcam and draw a bounding box around the changed pixels. The issue is that when I try to define the boundingRect (`x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours)`) it gives the error:

```
  Message=OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'boundingRect'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - array is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'
```

I've been searching around for quite a while but there seems to be a very small number of people who've had my issue and pretty much none of them had solutions that worked.

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
from time import sleep as wait
import numpy as np
 
lastFrame = "foobaz"

i = 0

#My webcam is on index 1, this isn't (at least shouldn't) be the issue. Make sure to set it back to 0 if you are testing
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
#A placeholder black image for the 'subract' imshow window
black = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

while(True):
    wait(0.5)

    ret, frame = vid.read()

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    blurframe = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame,(25,25),0)

    #Makes sure the lastFrame has been assigned, if not set it as placeholder black image.
    if lastFrame != "foobaz":
        #Subtracts current frame and the last frame to find difference.
        subFrame = cv2.subtract(blurframe,lastFrame)
    else:
        subFrame = black

    #Assigns the next lastFrame
    lastFrame = blurframe

    #Gets the threshold of the subtracted image
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(subFrame,40,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    #Sets the thresholded image to grayscale if the loop was ran for the first time.
    if i==0:
        thresh1 = cv2.cvtColor(thresh1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    i+=1

    #This is where issues arize. I'm trying to apply a bounding box using a contour but it always errors at line 44.
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]
    print(len(contours))
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours)
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('subtract',thresh1)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I saw that some other posts had the contour type() so here it is: 
`type(contours) = <class 'list'>`

**CLOSED: I found out the issue. You have to iterate `contours` for it to work.**

Comment: try `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect([contours])`. Note the square brackets

Comment: I tried it, it seems to throw the same error at me. The thing is, is that I found out that I was using the `cv2.findContours` function wrong. I just had to iterate `contours` instead of simply trying to make a bounding box around it. I don't know how I didn't find this out sooner.

Comment: instead of `[contours]`, which makes the problem worse, I'd recommend concatenating (flattening) them. `np.concatenate(contours)`. it really just needs to mash all the lists of points into a _single_ list of points. `boundingRect` considers the argument to be an unordered set of points, except it's got to be a numpy array (maybe accepts lists too, maybe not)